# How can I concatenate strings in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have made an iPhone application, but was trying to tinker with the title in one of my views. When I click on a state on the main page of my application it pushes to a new tableview and the title of the new table view will equal to the state that you chose you on the main page. For example: From the main screen you press the state of California, on the next tableview the title will equal "California", I want it to equal "California Areas".

```
destViewController.title = destViewController.stateName;
```

This is the line of code to where it sets the title and also where I feel the word "Areas" should be added. Can anyone assist me with some advice of how to accomplish this?

I feel like it should be something like this:

```
destViewController.title = destViewController.stateName + @" Areas";
```

But this doesn't work. I am very new to objective C, so excuse my ignorance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

`destViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Areas", destViewController.stateName];`

Update for comment, you could also do:

```
NSString *newString = [destViewController.stateName stringByAppendingString:@"Areas"];
```

I prefer the former simply because I think its easier to add and remove stuff to your string. But that being said, if its not going to change much the latter is a bit more succinct.

Comment: Prefer `stringByAppendingString:` in this case.

Comment: @JodyHagins `stringWithFormat:` is better for such a thing because it is easier to localize. Using `stringByAppendingString:` can't be localized.

Comment: @rmaddy Indeed! or `stringByAppendingFormat:` -- Why?  Because they will send `descriptionWithLocale:` if possible, otherwise `description` to the object being formatted.  OK, I'll buy that.  Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @JodyHagins You don't want `stringByAppendingFormat:` either. In some languages it is quite possible that `"Areas"` should appear before the name. So it's best to use one `stringWithFormat:` so the whole thing can be localized properly.

Comment: @rmaddy - OK, now you have me... how can the posted solution be reorganized by `stringWithFormat:`?  Granted, I've never had to worry about localization beyond simple key-value replacement, so this is strange water for me.

Comment: @JodyHagins Nothing needs to be changed for the `stringWithFormat:` solution other than localizing the format string.